# Change color of animated SVG on hover

Tags: css, animation, svg, sass

I am trying to change the color of this svg on hover to white, [here is my codepen](https://codepen.io/ishakumar98/pen/qBbGgXd). For some reason, using fill: `#fffff` under `&:hover` is not working. Any idea why?

```
body
  text-align: center

#flower-svg
    animation: loading-spinner 5s linear infinite
      &:hover
        fill: #fffff
        animation: loading-spinner 3s linear infinite 


@keyframes loading-spinner
   from
     transform: rotate(0deg)
   to
     transform: rotate(360deg)
```

Comment: You need to target the `path`s. Try `:hover path {fill: blue}`

Comment: Thank you so so much! That worked! The only thing is instead of covering the flower petals its covered the entire svg. By chance would you know how to just get it to cover the petals and not the white space in between? Thanks so much!

Comment: If I do stroke: white; it outlines the petals and the circle, and I want only the inside of that to be filled if that's clearer!